# retype password verification

Tags: javascript

Please give me some JavasSript code so that I can implement retype password verification while changing a password.

Comment: You also need to expand on the definition of "retype password verification"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very simplified, but the following code could be placed on the submit event of your form to check the two inputs when the user tries to save.

```
var password1 = document.getElementById("password1input"); // get a reference to the first input
var password2 = document.getElementById("password2input"); // get a reference to the second input

if (password1.value != password2.value) { // compare the values
    alert("They don't match!"); // alert the user
    return false; // prevent the form from submitting
}
```